# How to reformat the date on files in bulk using powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to format the file name from ...

```
2639423_3_30_56 PM_9_4_2020.txt
```

... to ...

```
2639423-15-30-56-09-04-2020.txt
```

i.e. Need to change date in Military time format and replace '_' with '-', Also append with “0” for single digit months and single digit days

Please advise I need to perform this in powershell & need to perform this in bulk.

Answer (score 2):

Start by splitting the file name into two parts - the prefix, which remains the same, and the timestamp, which you want to re-format:

```
$basename = '2639423_3_30_56 PM_9_4_2020'

$prefix,$timestamp = $basename -split '_',2
```

Next, parse the timestamp according to it's [specific format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings):

```
$inputFormat = 'h_mm_ss tt_d_M_yyyy'
$parsedDateTime = [datetime]::ParseExact($timestamp,$inputFormat,$null)
```

Finally convert the parsed `[datetime]` object back to a string with the desired output format, and then join the prefix and (updated) timestamp together again:

```
$outputFormat = 'HH-mm-ss-dd-MM-yyyy'

$timestamp = $parsedDateTime.ToString($outputFormat)
# or 
$timestamp = Get-Date $parsedDateTime -Format $outputFormat

$newFileName = $prefix,$timestamp -join '-'
# 2639423-15-30-56-09-04-2020
```

---

To rename the files in bulk, pipe the files to `Rename-Item` and use the parameter binder to generate the new name of each file based on the existing name:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path .\folder\with\files -Filter *.txt |Rename-Item -NewName {
  $prefix,$timestamp = $_.BaseName -split '_',2
  $parsedDateTime = [datetime]::ParseExact($timestamp, 'h_mm_ss tt_d_M_yyyy', $null)
  $timestamp = $parsedDateTime.ToString('HH-mm-ss-dd-MM-yyyy')
  $newBaseName = $prefix,$timestamp -join '-'

  $newBaseName + $_.Extension
}
```

Comment: This InputFormat is a powerful trick, nice answer, Mathias!

Comment: @FoxDeploy Thanks, `DateTime.{Try}ParseExact` is SUPER useful once you get the hang of the custom format strings :-D

Comment: Thank you Mathias, it work well with the single file but having issue with bulk operations getting below error:

Comment: Rename-Item : The input to the script block for parameter 'NewName' failed. Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" 
argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At C:\Users\caaroramo\covert.ps1:1 char:65
+ Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Test -Filter *.txt |Rename-Item -NewName {
+                                                                 ~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (2639423_3_30_56 PM_9_4_2020.txt:PSObject) [Rename-Item], ParameterBindingExce 
   ption

Comment: + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptBlockArgumentInvocationFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Comment: @Mona There was typo (missing `.` in `$_.BaseName`) in the sample code, I've corrected it now

Comment: Thank you so much @MathiasR.Jessen